# Code coverage tool for Visual Studio TDD Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tdd, code-coverage, googletest

My code is produced via Test Driven Development. My tools are Visual Studio 2010 express, Google Test, C++98 and the latest version of boost. I write my own Mock and am not using Google Mock.

What open-source tools would you recommend me so that I can establish my code coverage?

Comment: Note: If you are using VS10, you use some C++11 features under the hood, e.g. move semantics in the standard library, unless you defined _HAS_CPP0X=0

Comment: @Arne Mertz Yes, I have #define _HAS_CPP0X 0, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using gcov.

My setup is fairly complicated now that I'm having to think about describing it:
I've used the MinGW distro by stl, available at [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net/) for gcc (g++) and gcov.  This gives me some degree of portability.
I build my test application using scons and a batch file to build and run it to check it passes.

Then I commit code to version control and a Jenkins CI server running on my own machine picks it up, and still using scons, compiles it, but this time using the `--coverage` flag.  It runs the test app, which this time outputs the *.gc?? files.  Then I run gcov once, but telling it where all the files are, which produces loads of *.gcov files.  I have in the past used the python script `gcovr.py`, but I've since written my own to scan all the *.gcov files and print all the lines not covered.

I'm not sure of the open-source status of all those pieces, but I know they are free.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to Sonar with c++ Plugin. This tool not only helps you to look at code coverage but also other analysis for duplication and code quality, design quality etc.

http://www.sonarsource.org/ and [plugin](http://www.supertom.com/code/sonar-cxx-plugin.html)